# the toolbar up arrow icon displayed on bottom edge of toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am using following dependencies in my app.But the toolbar up arrow icon displayed on bottom edge of toolbar.Is it any problem in my code?

```
compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.appname"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
 }

dependencies {
    compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0') {
        force = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

**GalleryActivity.java**

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        TextView toolBarTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gallery_activity_toolbar_title);
        toolBarTitleTextView.setText(R.string.title_gallery_fragment);
```

**activity_gallery.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.company.appname.activities.GalleryActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gallery_activity_toolbar_title"
                style="@style/App.Widget.TextView.Toolbar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gallery_fragment"
        android:name="com.company.appname.fragments.GalleryFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_gallery" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `AppBarLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Main reason behind is `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` Its strange why its not working.

You can try this alternate solution.
Give this property in your style.

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  from CoordinatorLayout. It works great!